# When assigning A=B, does this call A's or B's assignment operator?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

If I have two classes A and B and I do A=B which assignment constructor is called? The one from class A or the one from class B?

Comment: You mean "assignment operator", right?

Comment: Assignment only makes sense for *objects*, not for *types*. It's like asking for `int = char;`.

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm assuming he wants the assignment between objects, not types, but that's a good point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's copy constructor and there's assignment operator. Since `A != B`, the copy assignment operator will be called.

Short answer: `operator =` from class A, since you're assigning to class A.

Long answer:

`A=B` will not work, since `A` and `B` are class types.

You probably mean:

```
A a;
B b;
a = b;
```

In which case, `operator =` for `class A` will be called.

```
class A
{
/*...*/
   A& operator = (const B& b);
};
```

The **conversion constructor** will be called for the following case:

```
B b;
A a(b);

//or

B b;
A a = b; //note that conversion constructor will be called here
```

where A is defined as:

```
class A
{
/*...*/
    A(const B& b); //conversion constructor
};
```

#### Note that this introduces implicit casting between B and A. If you don't want that, you can declare the conversion constructor as `explicit`.

Comment: Therefore I assume the syntax should be something on the lines: A& A::operator=(const B& from)

Comment: You assumed right that what i want is A a;B b; a = b; Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class abc
{
public:
  abc();

  ~abc();

  abc& operator=(const abc& rhs)
  {
    if(&rhs == this) {
      // do never forget this if clause
      return *this; 
    }
    // add copy code here
  }

  abc(const abc& rhs)
  {
    // add copy code here
  }

};

Abc a, b;
a = b; // rhs = right hand side = b
```

So the operator is called on the object on the left hand side.
**But make sure you do not miss the if clause.**